# Change language/locale in Nuxt/Contentful project

Tags: nuxt.js, contentful

How can I achieve dynamic language switching in Nuxt / Contentful project?

Content of `pages/index.vue`:

```
<template>
//...
</template>

<script>
import client from "~/plugins/contentful";

export default {
  layout: "landing_page",
  asyncData() {
    return client
      .getEntries({
        content_type: "landingPage"
      })
      .then(entries => {
        return { contentfulData: entries.items[0].fields };
      });
  },
  computed: {
    //...
  },
  props:[
    "displayApp"
  ],
  components: {
    //...
  }
};
</script>
```

Content of `plugins/contentful.js`:

```
const contentful = require('contentful')

const client = contentful.createClient({
  space: process.env.CONTENTFUL_ENV_SPACE_ID,
  accessToken: process.env.CONTENTFUL_ENV_ACCESS_TOKEN
})

module.exports = client
```

I have created two different locales for a specific model in contentful webapp:

[image]

however in the response I can see only one of them:

[image]

What have I missed?

Answer (score 0):

If there is only single page, then in the `pages/index.vue` you can use eg:

```
const getLanguage = () => navigator.userLanguage || (navigator.languages && navigator.languages.length && navigator.languages[0]) || navigator.language || navigator.browserLanguage || navigator.systemLanguage || 'en';

export default {
  layout: "landing_page",
  auth: false,
  asyncData() {
    return client
      .getEntries({
        content_type: "landingPage",
        locale: (getLanguage().includes('pl') ? 'pl' : 'en')
      })
      .then(entries => {
        return { contentfulData: entries.items[0].fields };
      });
  },
```

Works for two locales. The default locale is `en` in this example